# what do I have to add to have the same paragraph to print 3 times?

Tags: javascript

this is what I have done so far i needed help on adding a solution in (). I know i need to add a for loop but i am not sure where?

```
function getrandomnumber(min,max,notin)
{
    return min+Math.floor((max-min+1)*Math.random())
}

function roundnumber(num)
{
    return Math.round(num/10)/100
}  

{
    var a=getrandomnumber(50000,10000,"")
    var b=getrandomnumber(10,100,"")
    var c=getrandomnumber(50000,10000,"")
    var d=getrandomnumber(10,100,"")

    var total=(d-b)/(a-c)

    var str= "Luis's family decides to rent a hall for her "
    var s1= "retirement party. Pin Hall charges $"+a+" for "
    var s2= "the hall and $"+b+" per meal. Bloom place "
    var s3= "charges $"+c+" for the hall and $"+d+" per "
    var s4= "meal. Find the number of guests for which the charges are the same at both halls. "

    document.write(str+s1+s2+s3+s4);
}

document.write("<br><br>solution()");
```

Comment: Please read [ask] a good question. It's unclear to me what your problem is.

Comment: Your edit didn't really improve the question since. I still don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Simply put your code in a function all call the function inside a loop? `function solution() { /* code here */ }; for (/*loop header*/) { solution(); }`.

Comment: ok my first problem is that I need help to add a solution to my word problem

Comment: ya if you run my code in js.do the var s1,s2.... is a math word problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you are trying, You want to do as this example?

```
function getrandomnumber(min,max,notin){
   return min+Math.floor((max-min+1)*Math.random())
}

function roundnumber(num){
    return Math.round(num/10)/100
}  

function solution(){
    var a=getrandomnumber(50000,10000,"")
    var b=getrandomnumber(10,100,"")
    var c=getrandomnumber(50000,10000,"")
    var d=getrandomnumber(10,100,"")

    var total=(d-b)/(a-c)

    var str= "Luis's family decides to rent a hall for her "
    var s1= "retirement party. Pin Hall charges $"+a+" for "
    var s2= "the hall and $"+b+" per meal. Bloom place "
    var s3= "charges $"+c+" for the hall and $"+d+" per "
    var s4= "meal. Find the number of guests for which the charges are the same at both halls. "

    return (str+s1+s2+s3+s4);
}

document.write(solution())`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cq3uyLtv/

Comment: yes, so the next step is i want to add a solution (answer) to this word problem